# Bid/Ask Quotes displayed in a quote box

Tags: investing

What does the number beside the bid/ask price represent? In the example below, the 2 and the 4:

```
Bid 240.81   2
Ask 240.91   4
```

Comment: Where do you see that? My guess would be that it represents the order size.

Answer (score 3):

Bid 240.81   2
Ask 240.91   4

It means that 200 shares are bid at 240.81 (buyer) and 400 shares are asked at  240.91 (seller)

Size is displayed in round lots not shares (2 = 200 shares)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the order size. Usually it would be quoted as:

Bid 240.81 x 2 (meaning that the security last transacted at a price of 240.81 in the amount of 2 shares).

Comment: HK47: Bid 240.81 x 2 means  200 shares (2+ round lots).  The reason that I wrote 2+ is that any order for 200 to 299 shares will be displayed as 2.